# Postifx TLS certificate validation from clients on local subnet behind the firewall

Tags: ssl, postfix, certificate

I have a working postfix server behind firewall configured with graylisting, DKIM, SFP, amavis and clamav and properly configured MX, “A” record and reverse DNS entry. I can send and receive mails to other domains on the internet.  The postfix is using certificates from LetsEncrypt for the domain. The mail server is located on a private subnet lets say 192.168.10.0/24  behind the firewall. And in order to that to work  I am doing port forwarding for the following ports  25,587, 465, 993  as well as 80 and 443 for the certbot.  I have configured also  a manual static outband nat to resolve only to the public IP Address that is reserved for the mail server. So far so good  all works.

The problem I have is that that mail server is located in a  192.168.10.0/24 network and sending mail does not work for clients located behind the firewall in another local subnet (192.168.20.10/24) for TLS ports  i.e. 465 and 587, the 25 works!!!. If the clients are coming from outside all works well. Now every time those internal clients try to reach the mail server  they go  trough the firewall which is also a router in this case.  Those clients try to resolve the mail server lets say mail.mySimpleMailProject.com  and they see that the certificate is invalid since it’s maping to the wrong IP i.e.   192.168.10.5 and not the  public IP.

However i am able send mail from those internal clients only using port 25 and that works. But my target is to send the mail trough secure channel also in the internal network.

I have read about a possible solution  I.e.

**Configure Nat Reflection**

Now I really  really do NOT want to do NAT reflection, NAT is evil and I am trying to avoid it at all cost.

I am thinking of the following  is there a way to tell postfix to

1) accept  connection from local network

for that purpose I have the entry the permit_mynetworks in the smtpd_recipient_restrictions i.e.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,

    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,

    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,

    check_policy_service unix:postgrey/socket,
    permit
```

2) when  a connection that comes from internal network 192.168.20.0/24 to represent another self signed certificate that I can later import in those clients and make them happy.

Maybe there is some other better solution to this problem. 
Any hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**
You can have an internal DNS, that is solves, internally, the mail.mySimpleMailProject.com to internal address.

**Solution 2**
Make sure that port forwarding from internal networks towards the public IP resolved from mail.mySimpleMailProject.com are DNAT-ed (port forward).

Comment: Many thanks i configured split DNS in my local DNS resolver and now all request to mail.maSimpleMailProject.com are redirected to the internalIP.  However i already see a problem in the feature i.e. the clients that will use DNS over TLS i will be blind there. I am not sure  if that is the correct solution but it works.

Comment: Then you need to implement Solution 2  too.

Comment: well  as i mentioned in the question i am trying to avoid NAT by all means. so far this works without NAT but someone complains then i guess there is no way around it .  I was just interested if there is any other solution different from  Nat Reflection and split DNS but it seems that there is non. Many thanks for your help